# Create counter with multiple variables

Tags: r, counter

I have my data that looks like below:

```
CustomerID TripDate
1           1/3/2013
1           1/4/2013
1           1/9/2013
2           2/1/2013
2           2/4/2013
3           1/2/2013
```

I need to create a counter variable, which will be like below:

```
CustomerID TripDate   TripCounter
1           1/3/2013   1
1           1/4/2013   2 
1           1/9/2013   3
2           2/1/2013   1
2           2/4/2013   2 
3           1/2/2013   1
```

`Tripcounter` will be for each customer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `ave`. Assuming your `data.frame` is called "mydf":

```
mydf$counter <- with(mydf, ave(CustomerID, CustomerID, FUN = seq_along))
mydf
#   CustomerID TripDate counter
# 1          1 1/3/2013       1
# 2          1 1/4/2013       2
# 3          1 1/9/2013       3
# 4          2 2/1/2013       1
# 5          2 2/4/2013       2
# 6          3 1/2/2013       1
```

For what it's worth, I also implemented a version of this approach in a function included in my "splitstackshape" package. The function is called `getanID`:

```
mydf <- data.frame(IDA = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b"),
                   IDB = c(1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), values = 1:7)
mydf
# install.packages("splitstackshape")
library(splitstackshape)
# getanID(mydf, id.vars = c("IDA", "IDB"))
getanID(mydf, id.vars = 1:2)
#   IDA IDB values .id
# 1   a   1      1   1
# 2   a   2      2   1
# 3   a   1      3   2
# 4   b   1      4   1
# 5   b   2      5   1
# 6   b   2      6   2
# 7   b   2      7   3
```

As you can see from the example above, I've written the function in such a way that you can specify one or more columns that should be treated as ID columns. It checks to see if any of the `id.vars` are duplicated, and if they are, then it generates a new ID variable for you.

Answer (score 9):

You can also use `plyr` for this (using @AnadaMahto's example data):

```
> ddply(mydf, .(IDA), transform, .id = seq_along(IDA))
  IDA IDB values .id
1   a   1      1   1
2   a   2      2   2
3   a   1      3   3
4   b   1      4   1
5   b   2      5   2
6   b   2      6   3
7   b   2      7   4
```

or even:

```
> ddply(mydf, .(IDA, IDB), transform, .id = seq_along(IDA))
  IDA IDB values .id
1   a   1      1   1
2   a   1      3   2
3   a   2      2   1
4   b   1      4   1
5   b   2      5   1
6   b   2      6   2
7   b   2      7   3
```

Note that `plyr` does not have a reputation for being the quickest solution, for that you need to take a look at `data.table`.

---

Here's a `data.table` approach:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(mydf)
DT[, .id := sequence(.N), by = "IDA,IDB"]
DT
#    IDA IDB values .id
# 1:   a   1      1   1
# 2:   a   2      2   1
# 3:   a   1      3   2
# 4:   b   1      4   1
# 5:   b   2      5   1
# 6:   b   2      6   2
# 7:   b   2      7   3
```

Comment: I've never worked with `data.table`, only heard of its splendour and glory :).

Comment: @PaulHiemstra But you have worked with it. Was it only once? http://www.r-statistics.com/2011/08/comparison-of-ave-ddply-and-data-table/

Comment: It was a small test which I copied from someone else, see the SO post referred to in that post. I've been meaning to learn data.table, but have never felt the real need. Maybe my data is not big enough :).

Comment: Or use `seq_len(.N)` should be faster

Answer (score 7):

meanwhile, you can also use `dplyr`. if your data.frame is called mydata

```
library(dplyr)
mydata %>% group_by(CustomerID) %>% mutate(TripCounter = row_number())
```

Answer (score 3):

I need to do this often, and wrote a function that accomplishes it differently than the previous answers.  I am not sure which solution is most efficient.

```
idCounter <- function(x)  {
    unlist(lapply(rle(x)$lengths, seq_len))
}

mydf$TripCounter <- idCounter(mydf$CustomerID)
```

Comment: This is incorrect. You meant to use `sequence` which is *very different* from `seq_along`.

Comment: Try this instead: `idCounter <- function(x) sequence(rle(x)$lengths)`

Comment: @Ananda, Thank you for catching this, I accidentally typed "seq_along" instead of "seq_len" (now fixed above).  I was unfamiliar with `sequence`, and looking at `?sequence` I see that my function definition is similar to that of `sequence` (i.e., `sequence <- function(nvec) unlist(lapply(nvec, seq_len))`), except I replaced `nvec` with `rle(x)$lengths`.  Using `sequence` directly is definitely more elegant; however, being a relatively new R user, I find my longer version helpful because I can better follow the steps involved.

Comment: another point to note is that this approach would require sorting the data first if it isn't already sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the procedure styled code. I dont believe in things like if you are using loop in R then you are probably doing something wrong

```
x <- dataframe$CustomerID
dataframe$counter <- 0
y <- dataframe$counter
count <- 1
for (i in 1:length(x)) {
  ifelse (x[i] == x[i-1], count <- count + 1, count <- 1 )
  y[i] <- count
}
dataframe$counter <- y
```

Comment: Maybe you are not doing something wrong, but surely you will be doing something slow.

Comment: And I'd prefer the one-liner of @AnandaMahto over your 9 lines of code.

Comment: turns out, I wud prefer one liner too and I would surely benchmark to see my slowness

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the right answer but showing some interesting things comparing to for loops, vectorization is fast does not care about sequential updating.
    a<-read.table(textConnection(
    "CustomerID TripDate
    1           1/3/2013
    1           1/4/2013
    1           1/9/2013
    2           2/1/2013
    2           2/4/2013
    3           1/2/2013 "), header=TRUE)

```
a <- a %>%
group_by(CustomerID,TripDate) # must in order

res <- rep(1, nrow(a))  #base @ 1
res[2:6] <-sapply(2:6, function(i)if(a$CustomerID[i]== a$CustomerID[i - 1]) {res[i] = res[i-1]+1} else {res[i]= res[i]})
a$TripeCounter <- res
```