# Create a count variable in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to create a variable that counts starting from 1 for each unique value (of a specific variable or group of variables) in a data.table.

```
(mydata <- data.frame(cat   = c('a','a','a','b','c','c','c','c'),
                     color = c(  1,  1,  1,  2,  1,  1,  1,  1),
                     hat   = c(  1,  1,  2,  2,  1,  2,  1,  2),
                     shoe  = c(  0,  1,  1,  2,  1,  1,  1,  3)))
    cat color hat shoe
1     a     1   1    0
2     a     1   1    1
3     a     1   2    1
4     b     2   2    2
5     c     1   1    1
6     c     1   2    1
7     c     1   1    1
8     c     1   2    3

foo(mydata)
    cat color hat shoe  i
1     a     1   1    0  1
2     a     1   1    1  2
3     a     1   2    1  3
4     b     2   2    2  1
5     c     1   1    1  1
6     c     1   2    1  2
7     c     1   1    1  3
8     c     1   2    3  4
```

I was thinking something along the lines `mydata[, count = 1:length(Cat), by=.(Cat)]` but that does not seem to work.

I believe this question is distinct from [Create counter with multiple variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18487109/create-counter-with-multiple-variables) because it specifically asks about the implementation of data.table. However, the second alternative answer to that question is the same as the answer to this question, so I am okay calling this a duplicate. Apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You guess was very close, you just need to use `sequence`

```
> DT <- data.table(mydata)
> DT[, i := sequence(.N), by = cat]
> DT
   cat color hat shoe i
1:   a     1   1    0 1
2:   a     1   1    1 2
3:   a     1   2    1 3
4:   b     2   2    2 1
5:   c     1   1    1 1
6:   c     1   2    1 2
7:   c     1   1    1 3
8:   c     1   2    3 4
```

By changing `by` argument you can create other sequences depending on the groups of columns.

**Update**
As suggested in the comments by @veerendra-gadekar, it's possible to do it in even more compact way using `setDT`

```
> setDT(mydata)[, i := sequence(.N), by = cat]
> mydata
   cat color hat shoe i
1:   a     1   1    0 1
2:   a     1   1    1 2
3:   a     1   2    1 3
4:   b     2   2    2 1
5:   c     1   1    1 1
6:   c     1   2    1 2
7:   c     1   1    1 3
8:   c     1   2    3 4
```

Comment: just to be more compact you could use `setDT` like this `setDT(mydata)[, i := sequence(.N), by = cat]`