# R - Sequentially order data frame, repeat value if variable remains the same and change it when it changes

Tags: r

I have this data frame

```
    df <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5),
 school=c('school_1','school_2','school_3','school_3','school_4','school_5','school_1','school_1','school_1','school_4','school_6','school_7','school_5','school_5','school_8','school_10','school_10','school_10','school_12','school_13','school_7','school_2','school_2','school_13','school_2'))
```

and I would like to sequentially order it by id and school. If the school should repeat, I would want the same number used. Once the school changes, the seq should too. Ideal output is below. (I added breaks by id just so it's easier to read)

```
id  school  seq
1   school_1    1
1   school_2    2
1   school_3    3
1   school_3    3
1   school_4    4
        
2   school_5    1
2   school_1    2
2   school_1    2
2   school_1    2
2   school_4    3
        
3   school_6    1
3   school_7    2
3   school_5    3
3   school_5    3
3   school_8    4
        
4   school_10   1
4   school_10   1
4   school_10   1
4   school_12   2
4   school_13   3
        
5   school_7    1
5   school_2    2
5   school_2    2
5   school_13   3
5   school_2    4
```

I've tried:

```
setDT(df)[, sequence := seq_len(.N), by = c("id", "school")]
```

and per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18487109/create-counter-with-multiple-variables)

```
df[, .id := sequence(.N), by = "id,school"]
```

and neither produced what I wanted. Many of the suggestions don't have numbers repeating if the second variable doesn't change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, seq := rleid(school), by = id]

df
    id    school seq
 1:  1  school_1   1
 2:  1  school_2   2
 3:  1  school_3   3
 4:  1  school_3   3
 5:  1  school_4   4
 6:  2  school_5   1
 7:  2  school_1   2
 8:  2  school_1   2
 9:  2  school_1   2
10:  2  school_4   3
11:  3  school_6   1
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `match` + `unique` to get unique school number for each `id`.

This can be done using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(seq = match(school, unique(school)))

#      id school     seq
#   <dbl> <chr>    <int>
# 1     1 school_1     1
# 2     1 school_2     2
# 3     1 school_3     3
# 4     1 school_3     3
# 5     1 school_4     4
# 6     2 school_5     1
# 7     2 school_1     2
# 8     2 school_1     2
# 9     2 school_1     2
#10     2 school_4     3
# … with 15 more rows
```

Base R :

```
df$seq <- with(df, ave(school, id, FUN = function(x) match(x, unique(x))))
```

and `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, seq := match(school, unique(school)), id]
```